# How to call non abstract method in a abstract class?

Tags: python, abstract-class

I have an abstract class in python and want to call non-abstract methods in it.  Is it possible to do it?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class MyAbstract(ABC):

# Can I call method get_state() from get_current() ?
def get_state():
   get_current()  # gives me error?

def get_current():

@abstractmethod
def get_time():
```

I have another python file, Temp.py implement this interface.
In Temp.py, I call the `get_state` using `MyAbstract.get_state()`, I get the error stating that `get_current()` is undefined.

Not sure why.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please indent the code correctly and include the full traceback in your post

Comment: `get_current` *isn't defined*, at least not in the scope of `get_state`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, all methods have a namespace which is the class or object they're attached to. If you have an instance of a class floating around (e.g. `self`, most of the time), you can call methods on that instance that automatically pass the instance itself as the first parameter - *the instance acts as the namespace for an instance method*.

If you're using a class method or a static method, then the namespace is almost always going to be the class they're attached to. If you don't specify a namespace, then python assumes that whatever function you're trying to call is in the global namespace, and if it isn't, then you get a `NameError`.

In this case, the following should work for you:

```
class MyAbstract(ABC):
    def get_current():
        print("current")

    def get_state():
        MyAbstract.get_current()

    @abstractmethod
    def get_time():
        pass
```

You can just imagine that you have a little invisible `@staticmethod` decorator hanging above `get_current()` that marks it as such. The problem with this is that now you don't get to change the behavior of `get_current()` in subclasses to affect change in `get_state()`. The solution to this is to make `get_state()` a class method:

```
    @classmethod
    def get_state(cls):
        cls.get_current()
```

Calling a static method uses identical syntax to calling a class method (in both cases you would do `MyAbstract.get_state()`, but the latter passes the *class you're calling it on* as the first argument. You can then use this class as a namespace to find the method `get_current()` for whatever subclass has most recently defined it, which is how you implement polymorphism with method that would otherwise be static.